# Disable iPod at certain time

Tags: ios, jailbreak, screen-lock, tweaks

I find my self on my iPod (5th Gen) late at night (until 12 or 1 in the morning), and want to know if there is a Cydia tweak that locks me out of my device at a specific time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with `Activator`. After installing it in the Cydia you can assign Actions to the Events. For example you can assign this workflow:

```
Anywhere > Build > Scheduled > Sun,Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat 12:00 AM > Save > Done
```

Now select:

```
12:00 AM > Lock Device
```

Although this workflow just locked your device and does not **restrict** the usage after the 12:00AM, it acts like an alarm.

The other tweaks that can do the restriction are: [AppCap](http://ios.wonderhowto.com/how-to/cydia-tweak-caps-your-app-usage-your-iphone-so-you-can-be-more-productive-you-0142487/), [Parental Controls](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/09/19/parental-controls-for-ios-restricts-the-amount-of-time-your-child-spends-on-your-device/).